# Linking different user profiles in Google app Engine using python

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-plus, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I am building a social app on Google app engine using python, for which i am using Google+ api for user login and after login user can post and share.I need help in connecting one user profile to another so that user can see others post and follow them and also in displaying one's profile to another user. Like a user can browse public posts of all users, and if he clicks on creator of post, the link should open creator's profile with option of following him.I know to save user data in datastore and retrieve them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use the [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/), which can get you some information to the social graph and then access to the Google+ API. This information includes the ID of people in the user's circles that they've permitted you to see, so you can use this information to build their social graph.

If you have more specific questions, you should probably update your question (or post a new one) that demonstrates the exact problems you're having with the code.

Comment: I am fine with google+ API and am using it to login user and get his personal details and to setup his profile. I am stuck on how to link one profile to other and let users follow each other and brouse others profile.

Comment: You may need to clarify what you mean by "link one profile to other", but I have updated some of the info.